# SQLite database's been created but not the table (android)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

A lot of questions already have been asked about this but none of them seems to be working for me.
I open the file explorer>data>data>package name>database>mydatabase.db in order to get my database and i save it on my pc n try to see it using db browser for sqlite. But there's no table.
here's the helper class that extends sqliteOpenHelper:

```
package famiddle.smart.apps.businessmanager;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class BusinessDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

// If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "BusinessManager.db";
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

// SQL query for creating the table for items name
private static final String SQL_CREATE_ITEMS_NAME_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE itmes_name(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, items_name TEXT NOT NULL);" ;

public BusinessDbHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_ITEMS_NAME_TABLE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {

}
}
```

In my one of app's activity, I instantiate above class and run a method getReadableDatabase() so that the database can be created with the table.

```
package famiddle.smart.apps.businessmanager;

import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

public class PurchaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_purchase);

    // Instantiate the subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper.
    BusinessDbHelper dbHelper = new BusinessDbHelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

}
```

what do i do?

Comment: `close()` the database before pulling it to have the temp files (wal, shm) to be persisted to the db file. If that doesn't help, uninstall your app once to retrigger `onCreate()`.

Comment: @laalto I didn't close it in onDesrroy method of the activity but I again and again uninstalled my app nd reinstalled it.

Comment: Is there any problem with the software I'm using to see my database? Like I've mention in d question I'm using db for SQLite software.

Comment: Check your manifest for this line: `android:allowBackup="true"`. If it exists change it to `false`, uninstall the app and rerun.

Comment: @forpas just did it, but no success. Allow backup was true, turned it to be false.

Comment: Try the code in a clean device.

Comment: @forpas Meaning emulator?

Comment: Emultor or phone.

Comment: @forpas not working. I'd like to mention that I didn't put any values in the table so far, I wanted to see if I'm successful in creating database and its only table, then I thought I'd go ahead and work on crud operations.

Comment: @forpas I put values in the table and it didn't return - 1 meaning I added value successfully. But if there is no table then how it happened? Is there another way of looking at the tables besides db browser for SQLite?

Comment: If insert does not return -1 then the table is there. Extract from the device not only the database but also 2 other files with extensions BusinessManager-wal and BusinessManager-shm if they exist in the databases folder. Place them all in the same folder and then open the database.

Comment: @forpas yes they do exist nd I always extracted .db file n opened it with db browser. Will any software show the created table if it has no rows inside it?

Comment: If you have all 3 files in one folder and you open the database with DB Browser for SQLite you will see the table.

Comment: @forpas thank you man so much for your help! It worked! U solved my problem man. I feel like I should give you some money nd while writing it, I'm thinking there should be a site or an app that encourages developers to find a solution for a problem nd the guy will give some money to d solver. But then there's this site I know which works on no cost but only u n d other guy was there to give some attention.

Comment: It's fine if the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

Everything is fine with this code. I wasn't extracting two other files with the database file and wasn't putting it into one folder. When I did put all three files into one folder and opened the file with .db extension using the db browser for SQLite, I could see the tables.